# Jquery Mega Menu Master Page Issue with nested folder structure.

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am facing Jquery Mega  Menu Issue with my website
If i put Master page in my Module Directory then jquery works fine.
But if i moved the master page to the root then its not working for pages which are inside folders.
 I have checked that the pages which are in the root working fine with that master page which in root.

What i can do??
 Is it correct way to create master page for each folder unnecessarily ??

Answer (score 0):

Certainly sounds like a mapping problem.  The Mega menu should be reasonably isolated meaning you may need to utilise more precise mapping conventions, i.e. use ~/ or even / to refer to the absolute root of the ASP.NET site and house your jquery files as appropriate.

In addition, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or equilivalent should highlight any loading issues or Javascript errors within the console.

Comment: Hi!, Thanks for your answer. But i have used <script src="../Js/jquery.megamenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            Or         <script type='text/javascript' src='<%# ResolveUrl ("Js/jquery.min.js") %>'></script>                  But none of work. In firebug i found the file is mapping correctly. but run time when function calls and it try to apply css class it cant.

Comment: So it loaded the JS file (look at the 'NET' tab) and nothing appeared in the console?

Comment: XML can't be the whole program
http://localhost:1179/projectname/home.aspx
Line 360

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I got src='' in the page so it fires error "XML can't be the whole program"